# An exponential Diophantine equation.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

I'm solving an exponential Diophantine equation, and I've taken (mod 3) to have that $z$ is odd, but it's still hard for me .

" Find all the positive integers $x, y, z$ such that $7^x+1=3^y+5^z$ ".

Comment: See Leo J Alex, The Diophantine equation $3^a+5^b=7^c+11^d$, Math. Student 48 (1980) 134-138 (1984), MR 86e:11022.

Comment: Have you tried googling? eg I found https://msp.org/pjm/1982/101-2/pjm-v101-n2-p02-s.pdf. Also there are several possibly useful questions on this site. While these resources will not solve the problem for you, they will help you to make progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution only using modulo.

We want to find all the positive integers $x,y,z$ such that

$$ 7^x+1=3^y+5^z \tag 1 $$
Consider the equation $(1)$ in $\pmod 3$, we have
$$ 5^z \equiv 2\pmod 3$$
So $z$ is odd. If $y\ge 2$, then we can take $\pmod 9$ to have that $$ 7^x+1\equiv 5^z \pmod 9$$ Note that $ord_9(5)=6$ and $ord_9(7)=3$, we have:

If
$$x\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow z\equiv 3 \pmod 6$$
$$x\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow z\equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
$$x\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow z\equiv 5 \pmod 6$$

Now take $(1)$ in $\pmod 7$, we have
$$3^y+5^z\equiv 1 \pmod 7$$
So if
$$z\equiv 1 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow y\equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
$$z\equiv 3 \pmod 6\Rightarrow y\equiv 2 \pmod 6$$
$$z\equiv 5 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow y\equiv 5 \pmod 6$$

Then take $\pmod {13}$ we have
$$7^x+1\equiv 3^y+5^z\pmod {13}$$
Now consider all cases of $x$ in modulo 12, we found only one case is compatible: $x\equiv 2 \pmod 12$, $ y\equiv 1 \pmod 6$, and $z\equiv 7 \pmod 12$.

Now we can write $x=12k+2$, then $7^x+1=49^{6k+1}+1\equiv 0 \pmod 5\Rightarrow 3^y+5^z\equiv 0 \pmod 5$, contradiction.

So we conclude that $y=1$ and $7^x-5^z=2$. If $z\ge 2$ then take modulo 25 to have $7^x\equiv 2 \pmod {25}$, contradiction. So $z=1$ and $x=1$.

Hence $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ is the only solution for $(1)$.